# Does Java come pre-installed on Mac OS X 10.7/10.8 and beyond?

Tags: macos, java

Does Java (the JDK) come pre-installed with Macs on OS X 10.7/10.8 and beyond? I am hearing Apple is going to stop shipping Java with 10.8 and beyond but I couldn't find any link to confirm it/deny it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple did stop shipping Java as of 10.7 and higher. Neither the JDK nor the JRE come preinstalled. However, the first time you *need* a JRE, Mac OS X will offer to download and install it for you (via the Software Update mechanism).

Similarly, `javac` is stubbed in a base OS X install and will trigger the install process.

Note that the Apple JRE/JDK is Java 1.6—if you need 1.7 or 1.8, you'll need to [get it yourself from Oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml).

Answer (score 1):

The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is included with 10.8, but the Java Development Kit (JDK) is not - that you'll need to install yourself.

Comment: Could you provide a link from Apple or any sort of confirmation?

Comment: @user220755 this is just from personal experience looking at what's installed on my computer.